# Get a list of the licences of all packages on Ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, licensing, packages

I want to check what licenses all the packages on my system is running under.

It seems like this information is located in `/usr/share/doc/package/copyright`

However this file seems like it does not have any standard format, I've been going through this manually to record the licenses. is there another way to get this information, through something like dpkg-query?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Package licensing is far to complex for a simple answer single per-package answer.  Some packages, are covered by many licenses, some use non-standard licenses.  Do check out http://www.debian.org/legal/licenses/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884753/license-info-of-a-deb-package) suggests that automatically pulling the license info out of a single .deb package is non-trivial.

I suspect there is no easy way to do what you want.

---

Since the answer I linked to has been updated, I'll update mine too.

> This is beginning to change, as the `debian/copyright` file [is now required to be machine-interpretable](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/), so you can look forward to this in the future.

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to see if there was a easy way out :). Thanks